# Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type uint

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

AS3 FLASH

Can someone help me, why I can't "convert a string to a color"

```
var loadFeetColor2:String = 5435435

feet_cpicker2.selectedColor = loadFeetColor2;
loadColorInfo8_2.color = feet_cpicker2.selectedColor;
guy.guyanimation.foot2.colorMC2.transform.colorTransform = loadColorInfo8_2;
```

It's not work. But It's work:

```
feet_cpicker2.selectedColor = 5435435
loadColorInfo8_2.color = feet_cpicker2.selectedColor;
guy.guyanimation.foot2.colorMC2.transform.colorTransform = loadColorInfo8_2;
```

? why

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set something as a String literal you have to put it in speech marks, ie:

```
var loadFeetColor2:String = "5435435";
```

If, instead, you need that variable to be an int you should declare it as such:

```
var loadFeeColor2:int = 5435435;
```

Answer (score 0):

selectedColor method params would take unsigned integer only. You shouldn't pass a string. so try this.

```
var loadFeetColor2:String = 5435435   
feet_cpicker2.selectedColor = uint(loadFeetColor2);
loadColorInfo8_2.color = feet_cpicker2.selectedColor;
guy.guyanimation.foot2.colorMC2.transform.colorTransform = loadColorInfo8_2;
```